# Como eu faço para pegar variáveis php e passar para um arquivo JS diferente com ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

É o Seguinte eu quero passar uma variável do php para o Javascript só que em arquivos diferentes, eu tenho um modelo de código que é esse:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#botao").click(function(){    
     $.ajax({
     url:'../../../consulta.php',
     type: 'POST',
     var senha = document.getElementById('#senha').value;
     data: { senhap: 'senha',
     success: function (data){
     // me disseram que aqui o PHP me retorna alguma coisa, mas como eu vou 
     //tratar o resultado que vier por aqui?
     }
     });
     });
   });
```

Eu realmente nem sei se o código acima esta totalmente certo, alguém poderia explicar tanto o retorno do PHP quanto a parte do "data{senhp: 'senha',}" desde já agradeço!

Comment: E o restante do códgio? Qual a variável `PHP` que quer passar?

Comment: Apenas uma variavel $nome que esta no php, eu queria que fosse tres: $nome, $idade e $endereco, mas apenas nome por hora esta de bom tamanho, se der para que o js me mande um alert estaria feliz :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na sua função do PHP, você pode retornar algo assim:

```
return new JsonResponse(
                [
                    'success'=>true,
                    'nome' => $nome,
                    'idade' => $idade,
                    'endereco' => $endereco
                ]
            );
```

e no JS você acessa isso, dentro do atributo success, como: `data.nome, data.idade`, etc.
Espero que ajude!!